# Jenkins gitSCM seems to run fine based on the run log, but the code wasn't cloned

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I configured my pipeline script to use gitSCM. The pipeline run seems to complete successfully based on the run log, but when looking for the locally cloned repo it is nowhere to be found. I don't see any issues with the groovy script for the checkout() step. The code should exist in the relativeTargetDir, but again, it doesn't.

```
pipeline { 
   agent { label 'generic' }
   stages {     
      stage ("Git Checkout"){ 
         steps {
            script {
               checkout([
                  $class: 'GitSCM',
                  branches: [[name: '*/stability']],
                  extensions: [[
                     $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                     relativeTargetDir: "/var/jenkins/workspace/MyProject"
                  ]],
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[
                     credentialsId: 'repo_ssh_key',
                     url: 'git@github.durder.test.com:pipeline/automation.git'
                  ]]
               ])
                    
            }
         }
      }
      stage('Where is the repo code?') {
         steps {
            sh 'pwd'
            sh 'ls -l'
         }
      }
   }
}

Here is the Jenkins run:

Started by user myusername
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on i-0d50e9e9cc2678b71 in /var/jenkins/workspace/MyProject
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Git Checkout)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential repo_ssh_key
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/.git # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.durder.test.com:pipeline/automation.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.durder.test.com:pipeline/automation.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- git@github.durder.test.com:pipeline/automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 873cd7253b21b1b8c7e971bf7265164af79cb183 (refs/remotes/origin/stability)
Commit message: "Debugging Jenkins"
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/stability^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 873cd7253b21b1b8c7e971bf7265164af79cb183 # timeout=10
 > git rev-list --no-walk 873cd7253b21b1b8c7e971bf7265164af79cb183 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Where is the repo code?)
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/var/jenkins/workspace/MyProject
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -l
total 0
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need checkout, I think this is overcomplicating things.

Try this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'generic' }

  environment {
    BRANCH = '*/stability'
    URL = "github.durder.test.com:pipeline/automation.git" // not sure about the url we use https
    CREDENTIALS = 'repo_ssh_key'
  }

...

stages {     
  stage ("git checkout"){ 
     steps {
       git branch: BRANCH, credentialsId: CREDENTIALS, url: URL
     }
  }

...
```

I like to use env variables, you can easily modify that way. :-)

Comment: Thanks David! That is what I get for reading the docs. Using the simplified code I was able to see the following in the output:

stderr: fatal: '*/stability' is not a valid branch name.

Changed the branch name to 'stability' and it worked. I guess that wildcard was not expanded.

Comment: Yes, the /refs/heads/ is added automatically. You can see that in the output:
'code'
git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/stability" # timeout=10
'code'